# ItemSend Event Outlook for Windows Addin not firing

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

I am having trouble getting the ItemSend event to work for an Outlook addin I'm working on. I'm totally stumped as to what I've setup wrong.

The relevant parts of the manifest are as follows:

```
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
          <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
              <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
            </bt:Sets>
          </Requirements>
          <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
              <DesktopFormFactor>
                <FunctionFile resid="OnSend.Url"/>
                ...
                <!-- OnSend extension point -->
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
                  <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="onSendHandler"/>
                </ExtensionPoint>
              </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
          </Hosts>
        <Resources>
          ...
        <bt:Urls>
            ...
            <bt:Url id="OnSend.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/onsend.html"/>
            ...
          </bt:Urls>
          ...
        </Resources>
        </VersionOverrides>
      </VersionOverrides>
```

I then have onsend.js paired up with onsend.html, my onsend.js is very simple:

```
var mailboxItem

Office.initialize = function(reason){
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item
}

function onSendHandler(event){
    Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync("progress",{
        type: "progressIndicator",
        message: "Processing"
    })
    setTimeout(()=> event.completed(), 5000)
}
```

My Outlook version is as follows:

[image]

When I send an e-mail, there is a brief moment where a notification appears that says my add-in is working but no progress bar appears as in the code, and the 5 second timeout does not fire. It also fails to send if the server is not running, so I feel like it's picking up the manifest but just not running the function.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated!

EDIT: blank manifest and accompanying js code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>d49cc7b2-77eb-4c98-978d-0ce6e3745e4d</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="onsendtest"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.8">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
                <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="action" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                    <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                      <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
          <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
          <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

```js
Office.initialize = function(reason){

}

function action(event) {
  const message = {
    type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
    message: "Performed action.",
    icon: "Icon.80x80",
    persistent: true
  };

  // Show a notification message
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);

  // Be sure to indicate when the add-in command function is complete
  event.completed({allowEvent: true})
}
```

EDIT 2:
Getting this error when trying to run on the web:
[image: Outlook on the Web Error]

Comment: A couple of things to try - instead of adding a progress inforbar, for testing purposes, can you try adding an informational infobar instead. Does that work? Also, I would try using the replaceAsync on notificationMessages instead of addAsync to see if that works? Please let us know the results with your findings.

Comment: hello! thanks so much for your response. I tried the changes you suggested but unfortunately the same thing is happening. it's just a quick 'addinname is processing your request' and then the message sends successfully with no delay or informationalMessage.

Comment: if this helps at all, the addin causes the send to fail in outlook on the web - but the taskpane portion of it functions correctly.

Comment: Ahh. In the onSendHandler when calling event.completed, you need to pass in the allowEvent parameter. If set to true, send is allowed. If set to false, the email message is blocked from sending. This is what you need to use - event.completed({allowEvent:Boolean}). Here's a link to the documentation that states the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#notificationmessages-object-and-eventcompleted-method

Comment: thanks so much for continuing to help. I tried passing this object through but unfortunately got the same result. absolutely stumped. is there anyway I could attach a debugger to try and catch the script executing?

Comment: I even just tried making a fresh addin, and only having an ItemSend event present with te same results. Just a brief flash of onsendtest is working on your request and then it sends. Is it possible it could be my windows setup? I checked the group policies, they looked to match the walkthrough. I even tried loading up the example code with the bodyvalidation function and am having the same issue.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the manifest of this fresh addin that only has the ItemSend event so we can try it on our end? Could you also share your windows build number.

Comment: Done! I added it to the main body of the post in the edit section. I am running Windows 10 Version 1909 (18363.418)

Comment: Thank you for providing the manifest. The manifest includes localhost urls. Are you testing with localhost or have you added it for sharing purposes? We are unable to install and test the manifest with localhost in the urls.

Comment: testing with localhost, using the yo office generator, all stock settings. haven't deployed it yet due to the event handler not working.

Comment: I installed the manifest you provided and was able to get the OnSend feature working with local js and html, so I don't believe the issue is with the manifest. The issue is most likely with either your html or js. Here are a few things to check: 1. the FunctionFile element in the manifest points to the correct html file 2. your html page loads the correct js 3. your js contains your action function. There are some more code examples of OnSend implementations as a base for your implementation here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send

Comment: so strange. do you know if there are any policy settings or exchange / windows configurations that could prevent the addin from working? that's the last place i could think of. the basic addin also doesn't work in outlook on the web, so I suspect it's something configured by my IT department. also thank you so much for being so patient and helping me through this!

Comment: i've continued to try, everything loads just fine - it just doesn't ever seem to trigger the function i reference in the manifest. the commands.html file is coming through, office.initialize is succeeding - but my action function just never fires.

Comment: hello! still cracking at it, managed to finally get a warning / error from the addin on the web:commands.js:5933 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/838/g1xeucfv/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
(anonymous) @ VM13 commands.js:5933
triggerUnloadCallbacks @ VM13 commands.js:6293
unloadTriggered @ VM13 commands.js:6304

Comment: One more suggestion is to check that the JS function named in the manifest is globally defined (not nested within another object). If that doesn't help, you may also try using [Outlook-Add-in-On-Send](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) as a starting point to better understand at what point the command stops executing.

Comment: hello. after weeks of trying things, such as adding localhost to trusted sites - changing group policies, we are still unable to get the function listed in the manifest to fire. office.onReady works, but the function never fires. not even using the example linked. given that the addin also doesn't work in outlook on the web, are there any other configurations you could point us to that we could check? could this be something in our O365/Outlook on the web settings we've missed?

Comment: hello, i've made a bit more progress and seem to have narrowed the issue down to issues with webpack configuration. if i host the example code in browser-sync i run into no issues. but when using the yo office generated taskpane addin for outlook, the issue returns. do you know if others have run into a similar issue with webpack ?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone that comes across this, using the stock yo office webpack config doesn't seem to work with the ItemSend event. Not sure why - it could be something to do with how HtmlWebpackPlugin converts the file, I haven't dug too deep. What I ended up doing to get the ItemSend event to fire was add the following to the plugins section of the webpack config:

```html
plugins:[
    ...
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns:[
        {
          from: '[path to event handler code file].js',
          to: './'
        }
      ]
    })
 ]
```

You will also need to reference this file in your static ItemSend html file. If you try to pass the javascript along with the HtmlWebpackPlugin bundles, the function will not fire. Copying in the raw file itself was the only way I could get it to work. Hopefully this helps anyone who ran into the same problem as me.

Comment: did you try exposing your `onSendHandler` to the global scope with webpack?

Comment: what do you mean by `You will also need to reference this file in your static ItemSend html file.`